# Null Pointer Exception once again

Tags: java, object, reference, nullpointerexception, initialization

I asked this same question a while ago, and i was told to initialize my squareChecker variable and so i did. I still get the same error for some reason that i am unaware of. I have spent literally all day trying to figure out this problem by myself, but to no avail. Anybody know what my problem is?

My Normal Mode class (where i'm calling methods from square class and rendering things):

```
public class NormalMode extends BasicGameState {

    private Square[][] square = new Square[4][4];
    private Square squareChecker;
    Graphics g;

    public NormalMode() { }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame Game)throws SlickException {
        squareChecker = new Square(arg0);
        squareChecker.startGame(g);
        for(int i = 0; i < square.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < square.length; j++){
                square[i][j] = new Square(arg0);
                square[i][j].createRandom();
            }
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g)
                       throws SlickException{

        square[0][0].squareDraw(100, 300, g);
        square[0][1].squareDraw(150, 300, g);
        square[0][2].squareDraw(200, 300, g);
        square[0][3].squareDraw(250, 300, g);

        square[1][0].squareDraw(100, 400, g);
        square[1][1].squareDraw(150, 400, g);
        square[1][2].squareDraw(200, 400, g);
        square[1][3].squareDraw(250, 400, g);

        square[2][0].squareDraw(100, 500, g);
        square[2][1].squareDraw(150, 500, g);
        square[2][2].squareDraw(200, 500, g);
        square[2][3].squareDraw(250, 500, g);

        square[3][0].squareDraw(100, 600, g);
        square[3][1].squareDraw(150, 600, g);
        square[3][2].squareDraw(200, 600, g);
        square[3][3].squareDraw(250, 600, g);                   
    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta)
                       throws SlickException { }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return 3;
    }   
}
```

My Square Class:

```
public class Square {

    private StateBasedGame game;
    boolean correct;
    boolean clickable;
    boolean clicked;
    boolean started;
    int squares;
    int squareX;
    int squareY;
    public Image squareIncorrect;
    public Image squareCorrect;

    //For drawing these images from other classes
    {
        try {
            squareIncorrect = new Image("res/squareIncorrect.png");
        } catch (SlickException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            squareCorrect =  new Image("res/squareCorrect.png");
        } catch (SlickException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Square(GameContainer container) { }

    public boolean checkCorrect(){
        return correct;
    }
    public boolean checkClickable(){
        return clickable;
    }

    public boolean checkClicked(){
        return clicked;
    }

    public int returnNumberOfSquares(){
        return squares;
    }
    //Draw appropriate square on screen depending on the creatRandom. CREATE THE RANDOM FIRST!
        public void squareDraw(int x ,int y, Graphics g)throws SlickException{

            if(correct == true){
                g.drawImage(squareCorrect, x, y);
                started = true;
            }
            else if(correct == false){
                g.drawImage(squareIncorrect, x, y);
            started = true;
            }
    }

    public void createRandom(){

        Random rand = new Random();
        int sRand = rand.nextInt(2);

            if(sRand == 0){
                correct = false;
                clickable = true;
                clicked = false;
                System.out.println("This square is a phony!");
            }
            else if(sRand == 1){
                correct = true;
                clickable = true;
                clicked = false;
                System.out.println("This is a true Square!");
                squares = squares+1;
            }
        }


    public void youWin(int x, int y, Graphics g){
        if(squares == 0){
            g.drawString("You win!", x, y);
            try {
                wait(4000);
                game.enterState(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

    public void startGame(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Remember the blue squares! The game will start in 5 seconds!", 200, 300);

    }
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at data.src.Square.startGame(Square.java:112)
    at data.src.NormalMode.init(NormalMode.java:23)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:171)
    at org.newdawn.slick.ScalableGame.init(ScalableGame.java:69)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at data.src.Core.main(Core.java:30)
```

Comment: There's only one thing that can be `null` in your `startGame` method. Just follow the stack.

Comment: why do you think g (Graphics) would have a value?  No where (that I can see) are you getting a graphics ref.

Comment: @TMcKeown I have no idea what i'm doing. I'm still a newbie in progress, please forgive me for committing these programming sins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `NormalMode.Init()` you call `squareChecker.startGame(g);`

`g` is defined as `Graphics g;`.

`startGame()` calls `g.drawString()`.

This leads me to conclude that you don't instantiate `g` prior to passing it to your `startGame()` method.

Comment: Alright, i initialized Graphics in the square class, but it still won't work. I even changed the squareChecker to the update() method of normalmode to see if it works, and it did. The problem is that even though the game starts now, the method doesn't call or doesn't work since no string appears on screen.

Comment: That's an entirely different issue then. I suggest you run through the code with a debugger to see if your code hits all the methods you expect it to hit.